# Correct preposition to use in "To enter letters with/in lowercase"

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> To enter letters ***in*** lowercase.

OR

> To enter letters ***with*** lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say it either way, however, it is more common to say 'in lowercase' than 'with lowercase' [(in/with lowercase)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20lowercase%2Cwith%20lowercase&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20lowercase%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20lowercase%3B%2Cc0). The same applies to 'in uppercase' and 'with uppercase' [(in/with uppercase)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20uppercase%2Cwith%20uppercase&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20uppercase%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20uppercase%3B%2Cc0).

It is possible that this relates back to the days when printing was a manual process, with individual movable type pieces inserted into a frame to compose printed documents, e.g. newspapers, books, notices, pamphlets, etc. The type pieces were kept in cases, which had individual containers for each character. Traditionally,there were two cases, one for uppercase characters and one for lowercase characters.

Printing requires more lowercase characters, so it made sense for the case holding them to be closer to the typesetters. So, the case holding the uppercase letters was placed above the case holding the lowercase letters. So typesetters were used to sorting their lowercase type pieces 'in' the lower case, and their uppercase type pieces 'in' the upper case.